# Why isn't array of const structs placed in .rodata when it references a const struct by name?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, struct

I have the following arrangement of structs:

```
typedef struct { 
    int a;       
} Foo;

const Foo END = {0};   

const Foo table_1[] = {
    {2}, {0}           
};                     

const Foo table_2[] = {         
    {2}, END                    
};
```

Basically, I have a struct, and a couple of arrays of that struct. Now, the contents of these arrays never change: they are some lookup tables, that are used during runtime so, being in an embedded environment, I want that data to reside in ROM (I am *very* RAM-constrained, literally fighting for every couple of bytes). One would imagine, that there's nothing stopping all of those tables to reside in ROM (everything is const).

Actually, `table_1` ends up in `.rodata` (so it does not get copied into RAM during startup) and `table_2` - in `.data` (consumes both ROM and RAM). When disassembling the object file I can also see some code, that initializes `table_2`.

I want all aforementioned arrays to end up in `.rodata`, but it seems, that it will only happen if I write out the struct initializations "in full" (sorry, not sure, what is the correct term for this).

What is the difference in these initializations? Because it is only the initializations that are different - types are the same and the actual data is also the same. Is it some kind of optimization going on (wonder what's being optimized here)? Is there a way to disable it? I mean, I can just `#define` away all the common table members and be done with it, but it seems like a hack and, besides, I really want to understand what is going on here.

I am using gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain, building with `-Os`, gcc version is 4.8.1.

Comment: It looks like the compiler isn't able to optimize the case where a subexpression is not a literal, even if it's a `const` expression.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Maybe with C++ you could use `constexpr`.

Comment: Why would you want to disable the optimization? The optimization is what puts it in `.rodata` in the first example, that seems to be what you want it to do.

Comment: Try prefixing the definition (implementation) with `static`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ah, good catch, it is actually defined as `static` in real code. It makes no difference, though.

Comment: The difference is that `table_2[1]` is initialized by copying a diffenrent variable `END`. I wouldn't expect that `table_2` can be in ROM. The compiler might optimize that, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @harper @Barmar I did not know, that it mattered for this case (I haven't thought of C++-only constexpr). I will leave the `c` tag out then. It _is_ C++, no I can not use C++11 features

Comment: You can get complete control where which variable will be located by using a linker script. GNU ld also allows to place variables at specific addresses if that would be necessary.

Comment: `table_2` has a non-constant initializer (i.e. `END`). That is probably why it ends up in `.data`. It can't be resolved until the program is loaded and run, so it has to go there (i.e. the compiler/linker doesn't do it).

Comment: where are they going otherwise?  .text or .bss or something?

Comment: @dwelch See the paragraph beginning "Actually".

Comment: ahh, right, actually that kind of makes sense if you are not completely initializing it is ignoring the const.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gcc 5.1 and above perform this optimization; it is not mandated but considered by the C++ Standard, in [basic.start.init]:

> 3 - An implementation is **permitted** to perform the initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration as a static initialization even if such initialization is **not required** to be done statically, provided
>   that
>
> - the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of namespace
>     scope prior to its initialization, and
> - the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be
>     produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were
>     initialized dynamically.

If your version of gcc supports `constexpr`, then marking `END` `constexpr` should be enough to get it to statically-initialize `table_2`; you can also mark `table_2` `constexpr` to be sure (ibid):

> 2 - Constant initialization is performed: [...]
>
> - if [...] every full-expression that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.

Why do we need `constexpr` here - why isn't `const` sufficient? It's because a `const` object can still have a `mutable` member (possibly a member of a member, etc.) and that would allow it to be changed between the initialization of `END` and the initialization of `table_2`:

```
struct Bar { mutable int a; };
const Bar END = {0};
int unused = ++END.a; // !!
struct Foo { int a; };
const Foo table_2[] = { {2}, {END.a} };
```

`constexpr` prevents this in general, since [expr.const]/2 ensures that a composite object with a `mutable` member can't be used in the initialization of a `constexpr` object. A `constexpr` object can still have a `mutable` member of its own, but that would prevent it being used to initialize another `constexpr` object.

Comment: Re your retracted edit, this might be a silly question, but humour me... Is it defined to declare as `const` an instance of an object with a mutable member, then call methods that mutate said member? Or is it only valid if the object was originally declared non-`const`, meaning only the indirecting reference or pointer can be `const`-qualified? I'd always assumed the latter and never even pondered the former till now - and feel like it could go either way.

Comment: @underscore_d it's absolutely the former; an object that has a `mutable` member can have that member modified even if the object as a whole is declared `const` (and even `constexpr`).

Comment: Thanks! That does make a lot more sense. I just haven't yet needed `mutable` (for better or worse!), only `const_cast`, and hadn't consciously considered `mutable` properly till seeing your edit - so the two got mixed up and made me confused, heh. What are the implications of allowing that for `constexpr`? e.g. if the object's constructor modifies the member, meaning it's different by the time another `constexpr` can assign from it - is that all accounted for at compile-time? Please feel free to send me away to a good link on this!

Comment: @underscore_d can't think of any comprehensive articles, though the isocpp FAQ is pretty good: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#cpp11-constexpr A `mutable` member prevents an object - even a `constexpr` object - being used (as a whole) in a constant expression. A `constexpr` constructor can set members on a `constexpr` object - the idea is that the constructor is "simple" enough to be run at compile time, so the compiler knows the exact contents of the object and can (if necessary) lay it out in the rodata segment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming C++.

The initialisation of `table_2` is not a constant expression as per C++ standard. A constant expression is everything that does not have (among other things) a lvalue to rvalue conversion (which you have when you use `END`), unless the lvalue (the `END`):

> 1. Has integral or enumeration type and refers to a complete non-volatile
>      const object, which is initialized with a constant expression.

`END` is neither integral nor enum.

> 2. Is a non-volatile glvalue that refers to an element of a string
>      literal

`END` is not a string literal.

> 3. Has literal type and refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr or to its non-mutable subobject

`END` is not defined with constexpr.

> 4. Has literal type and refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evalution of this expression

`END`'s lifetime did not start within the evaluation of `table_2`.

So the compiler has no choice but to move the `table_2` initialisation away from static context. If you declared `END` with `constexpr`, I think the condition 3 will be satisfied and you will end up with everything nicely in `rodata`.

The relevant text from the C++ standard is in [expr.const] section, paragraph 2.7.2.

Comment: No trouble at all - just thought it'd be nicer to have that integrated into an already good answer, and means we can clean up these comments now! Oops - is it C++14 you're quoting? My PDF drafts are on another drive...

Comment: I usually download them from https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard, although technically they are the second-latest version.

Comment: "the compiler has no choice" - on the basis of the as-if rule, since the behavior will not be changed by static initialization, the compiler does have a choice.